# How to resize an image after selecting it from the gallery?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, image-uploading

In my application I want select image from gallery or capture image from camera and upload to server.

I want before send to server first resize this image with this size : `1000 x 600` then upload this.

My codes:

```
public class ImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView imageView;
    Button pickImage, upload;
    private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO = 2;
    private Uri mMediaUri;
    private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1111;

    private static final String TAG = ImageActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

    private Uri fileUri;

    private String mediaPath;

    private Button btnCapturePicture;

    private String mImageFileLocation = "";
    public static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Android File Upload";
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String postPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_layout);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        pickImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickImage);
        upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);

        pickImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        upload.setOnClickListener(this);
        initDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.pickImage:
                new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                        .title(R.string.uploadImages)
                        .items(R.array.uploadImages)
                        .itemsIds(R.array.itemIds)
                        .itemsCallback(new MaterialDialog.ListCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                                switch (which) {
                                    case 0:
                                        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO);
                                        break;
                                    case 1:
                                        captureImage();
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
                break;
            case R.id.upload:
                uploadFile();
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO) {
                if (data != null) {
                    // Get the Image from data
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    assert cursor != null;
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    // Set the Image in ImageView for Previewing the Media
                    Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
                    cursor.close();

                    postPath = mediaPath;
                }


            } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) {

                    Glide.with(this).load(mImageFileLocation).into(imageView);
                    postPath = mImageFileLocation;

                } else {
                    Glide.with(this).load(fileUri).into(imageView);
                    postPath = fileUri.getPath();

                }

            }

        } else if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, there was an error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Checking device has camera hardware or not
     */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected void initDialog() {

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_loading));
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    }


    protected void showpDialog() {

        if (!pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.show();
    }

    protected void hidepDialog() {

        if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
    }


    /**
     * Launching camera app to capture image
     */
    private void captureImage() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) { //use this if Lollipop_Mr1 (API 22) or above
            Intent callCameraApplicationIntent = new Intent();
            callCameraApplicationIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            // We give some instruction to the intent to save the image
            File photoFile = null;

            try {
                // If the createImageFile will be successful, the photo file will have the address of the file
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                // Here we call the function that will try to catch the exception made by the throw function
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Exception error in generating the file");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Here we add an extra file to the intent to put the address on to. For this purpose we use the FileProvider, declared in the AndroidManifest.
            Uri outputUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    photoFile);
            callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

            // The following is a new line with a trying attempt
            callCameraApplicationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Calling the camera App by intent");

            // The following strings calls the camera app and wait for his file in return.
            startActivityForResult(callCameraApplicationIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

            // start the image capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Generating the image - method started");

        // Here we create a "non-collision file name", alternatively said, "an unique filename" using the "timeStamp" functionality
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmSS").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "IMAGE_" + timeStamp;
        // Here we specify the environment location and the exact path where we want to save the so-created file
        File storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/photo_saving_app");
        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Storage directory set");

        // Then we create the storage directory if does not exists
        if (!storageDirectory.exists()) storageDirectory.mkdir();

        // Here we create the file using a prefix, a suffix and a directory
        File image = new File(storageDirectory, imageFileName + ".jpg");
        // File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDirectory);

        // Here the location is saved into the string mImageFileLocation
        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("File name and path set");

        mImageFileLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();
        // fileUri = Uri.parse(mImageFileLocation);
        // The file is returned to the previous intent across the camera application
        return image;
    }


    /**
     * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
     * app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }


    /**
     * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
     * */

    /**
     * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
     * */

    /**
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /**
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    // Uploading Image/Video
    private void uploadFile() {
        if (postPath == null || postPath.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "please select an image ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        } else {
            showpDialog();

            // Map is used to multipart the file using okhttp3.RequestBody
            Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
            File file = new File(postPath);

            // Parsing any Media type file
            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
            map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"", requestBody);
            ApiConfig getResponse = AppConfig.getRetrofit().create(ApiConfig.class);
            Call<ServerResponse> call = getResponse.upload("token", map);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            hidepDialog();
                            ServerResponse serverResponse = response.body();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    } else {
                        hidepDialog();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "problem uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    hidepDialog();
                    Log.v("Response gotten is", t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: what exactly is a problem? Have you tried to search for `android resize bitmap`?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this class**

ImageCompression.java

```
public class ImageCompression {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = ImageCompression.class.getSimpleName();
    static volatile ImageCompression singleton = null;
    private static Context mContext;

    public ImageCompression(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Initialise the class and set the context
     */
    public static ImageCompression with(Context context) {
        if (singleton == null) {
            synchronized (ImageCompression.class) {
                if (singleton == null) {
                    singleton = new Builder(context).build();
                }
            }
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    /**
     * Compresses the image at the specified Uri String and and return the filepath of the compressed image.
     *
     * @param imageUri imageUri Uri (String) of the source image you wish to compress
     * @return filepath
     */
    public String compress(String imageUri) {
        return compressImage(imageUri, destinationFile());
    }

    /**
     * Compresses the image at the specified Uri String and and return the filepath of the compressed image.
     *
     * @param imageUri imageUri Uri (String) of the source image you wish to compress
     * @return filepath
     */

    public String compress(String imageUri, boolean deleteSourceImage) {
        String compressUri = compress(imageUri);
        if (deleteSourceImage) {
            File source = new File(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));
            if (source.exists()) {
                boolean isdeleted = source.delete();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, (isdeleted) ? "SourceImage File deleted" : "SourceImage File not deleted");
            }
        }
        return compressUri;
    }

    public String compress(int drawableID) throws IOException {
        // Create a bitmap from this drawable
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getApplicationContext().getResources(), drawableID);
        if (null != bitmap) {
            // Create a file from the bitmap
            // Create an image file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File image = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",  /* suffix */
                    storageDir     /* directory */
            );
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(image);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

            // Compress the new file
            Uri copyImageUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
            String compressImagePath = compressImage(copyImageUri.toString(), new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ImageCompression/images"));

            // Delete the file create from the drawable Id
            if (image.exists()) {
                boolean isdeleted = image.delete();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, (isdeleted) ? "SourceImage File deleted" : "SourceImage File not deleted");
            }

            // return the path to the compress image
            return compressImagePath;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Compresses the image at the specified Uri String and and return the bitmap data of the compressed image.
     *
     * @param imageUri imageUri Uri (String) of the source image you wish to compress
     * @return Bitmap format of the new image file (compressed)
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Bitmap getCompressBitmap(String imageUri) throws IOException {
        File imageFile = new File(compressImage(imageUri, new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ImageCompression/images")));
        Uri newImageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mContext.getContentResolver(), newImageUri);
        return bitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Compresses the image at the specified Uri String and and return the bitmap data of the compressed image.
     *
     * @param imageUri          Uri (String) of the source image you wish to compress
     * @param deleteSourceImage If True will delete the source file
     * @return Compress image bitmap
     * @throws IOException
     */

    public Bitmap getCompressBitmap(String imageUri, boolean deleteSourceImage) throws IOException {
        File imageFile = new File(compressImage(imageUri, new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ImageCompression/images")));
        Uri newImageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mContext.getContentResolver(), newImageUri);
        if (deleteSourceImage) {
            File source = new File(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));
            if (source.exists()) {
                boolean isdeleted = source.delete();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, (isdeleted) ? "SourceImage File deleted" : "SourceImage File not deleted");
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Do the actual compression of this image
     *
     * @param imageUri      source image file to compress
     * @param destDirectory destination directory to place image in
     * @return uri string of the compressed image
     */
    private String compressImage(String imageUri, File destDirectory) {

        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        //by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
        //you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        //max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612
        float maxHeight = 1280.0f;//816.0f;
        float maxWidth = 1280.0f;//612.0f;

        //width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image
        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;
        float imgRatio = (float) actualWidth / (float) actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            }
        }

        //setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

        //inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        //this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
            //load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } /*catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        //check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.e("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.e("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.e("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.e("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String filename = getFilename(imageUri, destDirectory);
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            //write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return filename;
    }

    private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;
        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }
        final float totalPixels = width * height;
        final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;
        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

    private String getFilename(String filename, File file) {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String ext = ".jpg";
        //get extension
        /*if (Pattern.matches("^[.][p][n][g]", filename)){
            ext = ".png";
        }*/
        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/IMG_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date()) + ext);
    }

    /**
     * Gets a valid path from the supply contentURI
     *
     * @param contentURI
     * @return A validPath of the image
     */
    private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            String str = cursor.getString(index);
            cursor.close();
            return str;
        }
        // return  FileUtils.getPath(mContext, contentUri);
        // return  getRealPathFromURI_API19(mContext, contentUri);
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri) {
        String filePath = "";
        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

        // Split at colon, use second item in the array
        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];
        String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        // where id is equal to
        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    }

    /**
     * Fluent API for creating {@link ImageCompression} instances.
     */
    public static class Builder {
        private final Context context;

        /**
         * Start building a new {@link ImageCompression} instance.
         */
        public Builder(Context context) {
            if (context == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context must not be null.");
            }
            this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        }

        /**
         * Create the {@link ImageCompression} instance.
         */
        public ImageCompression build() {
            Context context = this.context;
            return new ImageCompression(context);
        }
    }

    public File destinationFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Android/data/"
                + mContext.getPackageName()
                + "/Image/Compressed");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists())
            mediaStorageDir.mkdir();
        return mediaStorageDir;
    }

  /*boolean isCompressSuccess = false;
    public String compressVideo(final String videoFilePath) throws URISyntaxException {
        final String destinationPath = destinationFile().getAbsolutePath();
        isCompressSuccess = MediaController.getInstance().convertVideo(videoFilePath, destinationPath);
        if(isCompressSuccess)
            return destinationPath;
        else
            return "";
    }*/

    public void deleteFiles() {
        try
        {
            new AsyncTask()
            {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects)
                {
                    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/Android/data/"
                            + mContext.getPackageName()
                            + "/Image/Compressed");
                    if (mediaStorageDir.listFiles() != null && mediaStorageDir.listFiles().length > 0) {
                        for (File file : mediaStorageDir.listFiles())
                            if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                                //file.delete();
                            }
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

pass Parameter like this

```
String filePath =ImageCompression.with(getApplicationContext()).compress(imagePath.toString(),   false);
File file = new File(filePath);
```

Comment: There is missing a `.resizeto(1000,600).` in the call.

Comment: You have a nice class. But all those getRealPathFromURI() functions. Terrible! One does not do such awfull things. You should adapt to modern times. Do away with them and use provided content scheme uris directly. It will make all much nicer.

Comment: @greenapps  you can use `compressImage(String imageUri, File destDirectory)` this method according your requirement. and This class used for without loseing a file(picture) quality give a result like a whatsapp appplication images.

Comment: You should add it to your class. Certainly if you advertise it as solution for this post.

Comment: I really dont understand why you are talking about Picasso. If the function name is not right for you you could name it .resolution(int,int).  or wxh(int,int). Whats in a name?

Comment: @greenapps dude this compression is done as per image proportion.

Answer (score 0):

```
use getResized in onActivityForResult  

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else { 
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        } 
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```

Comment: can you send to me code with my codes? i use this code and i can resize it. but when send image, i send file! how can i it? please help me, really need your help

Comment: you need send file to server using multipart request:here is link to get reference https://blog.aimanbaharum.com/2016/03/26/android-image-multi-part-upload/

Comment: yes i know and i use multipart and you can see in my code! but i don't know how to cast bitmap to file. can you read my code and help to me with my code?

Comment: can You tell which error do u face while uploading method is called in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity Code

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Android File Upload";
private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO = 2;
private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1111;
private static final String TAG = ImageActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
ImageView imageView;
Button pickImage, upload;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
private Uri fileUri;
private String mediaPath;
private String mImageFileLocation = "";
private String postPath;

/**
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_layout);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
    pickImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickImage);
    upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);

    pickImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    upload.setOnClickListener(this);
    initDialog();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.pickImage:

            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
                //File write logic here
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.upload:
            uploadFile();
            break;
    }
}

private boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Permission: " + permissions[0] + "was " + grantResults[0]);
        //resume tasks needing this permission
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO) {
            if (data != null) {
                // Get the Image from data
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                assert cursor != null;
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                // Set the Image in ImageView for Previewing the Media
                Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath);
                bitmapImage = getResizedBitmap(bitmapImage, 400);// 400 is for example, replace with desired size
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);

                cursor.close();

                postPath = mediaPath;
            }


        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) {

                Glide.with(this).load(mImageFileLocation).into(imageView);
                postPath = mImageFileLocation;

            } else {
                Glide.with(this).load(fileUri).into(imageView);
                postPath = fileUri.getPath();

            }

        }

    } else if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, there was an error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Checking device has camera hardware or not
 */
private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

protected void initDialog() {

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_loading));
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
}

protected void showpDialog() {

    if (!pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.show();
}

protected void hidepDialog() {

    if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
}

/**
 * Launching camera app to capture image
 */
private void captureImage() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) { //use this if Lollipop_Mr1 (API 22) or above
        Intent callCameraApplicationIntent = new Intent();
        callCameraApplicationIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        // We give some instruction to the intent to save the image
        File photoFile = null;

        try {
            // If the createImageFile will be successful, the photo file will have the address of the file
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            // Here we call the function that will try to catch the exception made by the throw function
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Exception error in generating the file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Here we add an extra file to the intent to put the address on to. For this purpose we use the FileProvider, declared in the AndroidManifest.
        Uri outputUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                this,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                photoFile);
        callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

        // The following is a new line with a trying attempt
        callCameraApplicationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Calling the camera App by intent");

        // The following strings calls the camera app and wait for his file in return.
        startActivityForResult(callCameraApplicationIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    }
}

File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Generating the image - method started");

    // Here we create a "non-collision file name", alternatively said, "an unique filename" using the "timeStamp" functionality
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmSS").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "IMAGE_" + timeStamp;
    // Here we specify the environment location and the exact path where we want to save the so-created file
    File storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/photo_saving_app");
    Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Storage directory set");

    // Then we create the storage directory if does not exists
    if (!storageDirectory.exists()) storageDirectory.mkdir();

    // Here we create the file using a prefix, a suffix and a directory
    File image = new File(storageDirectory, imageFileName + ".jpg");
    // File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDirectory);

    // Here the location is saved into the string mImageFileLocation
    Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("File name and path set");

    mImageFileLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();
    // fileUri = Uri.parse(mImageFileLocation);
    // The file is returned to the previous intent across the camera application
    return image;
}

/**
 * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
 * app
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}


/**
 * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 * */

/**
 * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
 */

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}

/**
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}


public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}

// Uploading Image/Video
private void uploadFile() {
    if (postPath == null || postPath.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "please select an image ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    } else {
        showpDialog();

        // Map is used to multipart the file using okhttp3.RequestBody
        Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
        File file = new File(postPath);


        // Parsing any Media type file
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);
        RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());


        ApiConfig getResponse = AppConfig.getRetrofit().create(ApiConfig.class);
        Call<ServerResponse> call = getResponse.uploadFile(fileToUpload, filename);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        hidepDialog();
                        ServerResponse serverResponse = response.body();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    hidepDialog();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "problem uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                hidepDialog();
                Log.v("Response gotten is", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

====AppConfig Class=======`

```
public class AppConfig {

private static String BASE_URL = "yourbase URL";

static Retrofit getRetrofit() {

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

}
`=======Interface Config===========`

```
interface ApiConfig {
@Multipart
@POST("retrofit_example/upload_image.php")
Call<ServerResponse> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                @Part("file") RequestBody name);

@Multipart
@POST("retrofit_example/upload_multiple_files.php")
Call<ServerResponse> uploadMulFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file1,
                                   @Part MultipartBody.Part file2);
```

}

Comment: thanks dear, but in your codes  you  resize image just for set into imageView, but for send image you send with full size! i want send image with my new size. can you help me?

Comment: okey give me some time I am busy as of now but do vote up answer man

Answer (score 0):

> use this class :

```
public class CompressFile {
    public static File getCompressedImageFile(File file, Context mContext) {
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            if (getFileExt(file.getName()).equals("png") || getFileExt(file.getName()).equals("PNG")) {
                o.inSampleSize = 6;
            } else {
                o.inSampleSize = 6;
            }

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o);
            inputStream.close();

            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE &&
                    o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                scale *= 2;
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            Bitmap selectedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o2);

            ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());
            int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

            switch (orientation) {

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotateImage(selectedBitmap, 90);
                    break;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotateImage(selectedBitmap, 180);
                    break;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotateImage(selectedBitmap, 270);
                    break;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:

                default:
                    break;
            }
            inputStream.close();


            // here i override the original image file
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FolderName");
            boolean success = true;
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                success = folder.mkdir();
            }
            if (success) {
                File newFile = new File(new File(folder.getAbsolutePath()), file.getName());
                if (newFile.exists()) {
                    newFile.delete();
                }
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

                if (getFileExt(file.getName()).equals("png") || getFileExt(file.getName()).equals("PNG")) {
                    selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
                } else {
                    selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                }

                return newFile;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String getFileExt(String fileName) {
        return fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileName.length());
    }

    public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);
    }
}
```